# Detached branch after installing laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've installed laravel and now I see a second branch:

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Development\php\carpool>git branch
* (detached from v5.2.0)
  master
```

Is that correct or should I do something?

Thanks!

Comment: You must have checked out specific commit and ended up in detached state. "git checkout master" will get you back to master branch and get rid of detached commit.